# What is the cosmological redshift drift effect?

Tags: cosmology, redshift

What is the redshift drift effect in cosmology?
What are the necessary cosmological conditions for there to be a measurable redshift drift effect?

Comment: The *redshift drift* of an astronomical object is just the change of the redshift of that object with time. I think you'll need to be clearer what you want to know for us to be able to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redshift drift is the name given to the effect whereby as the universe expands, the redshift of an object will *change with time.* i.e. It will drift.

A galaxy at a fixed co-moving distance will have a redshift that changes with time and the first and second time derivatives of the redshift may prove to be valuable probes of cosmological models (e.g. [Meliá 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.00047)).

The size of the effect is of order 10  cm/s/yr, with the difference between different cosmological models being smaller than this. It is expected that the E-ELT telescope may be able to measure redshift drift over 5-year periods, using large ensembles of galaxies at similar redshifts.

An expression for the first order redshift drift is
$$\frac{dz}{dt_0}= (1+z)H_0 - H(z),$$
where $H_0$ is the current Hubble parameter at time $t_0$ and $H(z)$ is the value of the Hubble parameter at an epoch corresponding to a redshift $z$.

The condition that there be a redshift drift is therefore that 
$$ H(z) \neq (1+z)H_0$$
which is certainly the case for arbitrary values of $z$ in $\Lambda$CDM cosmology$^*$ where
$$H(z) = (1+z) H_0\left[ \Omega_r (1+z)^2 + \Omega_m (1+z) + \Omega_k + \Omega_{\Lambda}(1+z)^{-2}\right]^{1/2}$$
and the condition for a redshift drift is that
$$\left[ \Omega_r (1+z)^2 + \Omega_m (1+z) + \Omega_k + \Omega_{\Lambda}(1+z)^{-2}\right] \neq 1$$

$^*$ Other cosmologies are possible...