# Calculating the redshift drift

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

I am trying to calculate the **redshift drift** where its written as

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = (1+z)H_0 - H \tag{1}$$

We also know that $$1+z = a(t_o) / a(t_e) \tag{2}$$

and $$H_0 = \frac{\dot{a}(t_0)}{a(t_0)}$$

$$H = \frac{\dot{a}(t_e)}{a(t_e)}$$

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400386/

Comment: Layla, can you specify your problem? If you know the scale factors then the redshift is given by your equation (2).

Comment: @psm What information do you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an inaccuracy in the first equation regarding "H". Normally in the context of differentiating with respect to t, functions are assumed to be having a function of t as an argument, and if none is given, then it is normally assumed that H=H(t). In the case of your equation, H=H(z)=H(z(t)). See

[What is the cosmological redshift drift effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400386/what-is-the-cosmological-redshift-drift-effect#400445) .

I suggest the other equations should also be in terms of z rather than t. You should also note that z(t0)=0, and z(t)=(1/a(t))-1.

I hope this helps.